# How do I work with the mask data for AI4 boundaries?

Tags: python, image

I am working with the Ai4Boundaries dataset and while the data in the imagery folder is opening with Windows Photos + causing no issues in the python code I'm reading it into, the data in the mask folder will only open on ArcMap (as a black-blue gradient) and is causing errors in my code. (Both the imagery and the mask are in tiff format).

Here is a link to the

- [Imagery](https://jeodpp.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/DRLL/AI4BOUNDARIES/orthophoto/images/AT/)
- [Masks](https://jeodpp.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/DRLL/AI4BOUNDARIES/orthophoto/masks/AT/)

When I simply try and open a mask using python with this code

```
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread('/content/AT_2989_ortholabel_1m_512.tif'))
```

the error I get is

```
UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/content/AT_2989_ortholabel_1m_512.tif'
```

Any leads as to what the issue is and how I can resolve it?

I tried converting a mask to png and the png file is working fine on my code. But I'm working with around 7k+ images and don't know how to bulk convert.

Comment: So I've realized that the error is because the mask imagery is 4 band instead of 3 bands. Can someone help me on how I can work with it or mass convert 7k+ images from 4 bands to 3 bands?

Comment: I suggest having look at this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246559/is-it-possible-to-read-in-specific-bands-from-a-multi-band-raster-with-gdal-or-r